# Placing User Input into Table and Sum the Total in Lua

Tags: lua, sum, user-input, lua-table

I'm attempting to make a script on my own that would be beneficial for technicians/salesmen in the field.  There are three products that make up this product line.  But the only difference between these products are the sizes.  Each size contains a certain amount of brackets required to mount them.  For the small, only one is necessary.  For the medium, two.  And for the large, four.

I want my script to issue a prompt asking the user for how many of each type of product, as any installation can have any amount of a mixture of these product sizes. (sorry if this is confusing, but hopefully my code below will help explain better.)  I would ideally like this script to take the amount of each product size needed, add them up and spit out the total amounts of brackets required for the installation.  Right now, I cannot figure out how badly I am butchering this code as I am new to programming.

Please review the code below and any help and/or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

```
function (t)
    local t = {}
    a,b = i,brackets
    io.write ("Enter Total Number of Small Products")
    answer = io.read()
    if answer then
        brackets = table.insert (t,#t+1,(answer * 1))
    end
    io.write ("Enter Total Number of Medium Products")
    answer = io.read()
    if answer then
        brackets = table.insert (t,#t+1,(answer * 2))
    end
    io.write ("Enter Total Number of Large Products")
    answer = io.read()
    if answer then
        brackets = table.insert (t,#t+1,(answer * 4))
    end
    local sum = 0
    for i,brackets in ipairs (t) do
        sum = sum + brackets
    end
    print (sum)
end
```

Comment: Why do you declare a local table `t` with the same name of the function parameter (the `t` parameter is useless in this case, since it is hidden by the local `t`)? How should this function be used?

Comment: Moreover what is the purpose of `a,b = i,brackets`? They involve variables not defined in your function. Please always post a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted has a number of problems. If the only requirements you have are those you stated, the following script use a function to perform the input and the computation of the sum, which is returned as a result.

```
local function GetSum()
    local sum = 0
    local answer
    io.write ("Enter Total Number of Small Products: ")
    answer = io.read()
    if answer then
        sum = sum + tonumber( answer )
    end
    io.write ("Enter Total Number of Medium Products: ")
    answer = io.read()
    if answer then
        sum = sum + 2 * tonumber( answer )
    end
    io.write ("Enter Total Number of Large Products: ")
    answer = io.read()
    if answer then
        sum = sum + 4 * tonumber( answer )
    end
    return sum
end


print( GetSum() )
```

Note: the calls to the `tonumber` function are not necessary, since Lua coerces the string in `answer` into a number in that context, but in a bigger application it is useful to be explicit so that the reader can clearly spot that a type conversion is being done.

Comment: Thank you for the help again, Lorenzo!  That makes complete sense.  When I read other's code, I understand it.  But when I try to make my own from start, I'm practically lost on what to do!  But your code is so completely easy that I'm kicking myself for posting that atrocity of a script above. Thank you again, Lorenzo!!!

Answer (score 3):

I see several issues here that I'd raise:

1. Your code is all contained in an anonymous function. While this is syntactically valid, you haven't shown that this function is captured and eventually called. A simple script is largely written at file scope, although there are times when writing `function main() --[[stuff happens]] end` can make sense. Especially if instead of just writing `main()` you write something like `pcall(main)` to capture and handle any errors it threw.
2. Your anonymous function is declared to take a parameter named `t`. That parameter is then immediately shadowed by the local variable named `t`, and cannot be accessed at all inside the function.
3. You clearly know about local variables. So why are you using globals named `a`, `b`, `i`, `brackets` and `answer`?
4. The variables `a`, and `b` are not used again, and `i` and `brackets` are shadowed by the locals created by the `for` loop later.
5. You know about functions, so you should notice your repeated code that prompts and reads for a value, and collect that into a function.
6. `table.insert` isn't documented to return a value.
7. You are using `t` as an array, which is a pattern that `table.insert` already knows about so the second argument of `#t+1` is redundant. If missing, that is where `table.insert` will put the value.
8. You call `table.insert`, `io.read`, and `io.write` frequently. Current best practices suggest that copying those functions into local variables will speed up their access by eliminating the access to the global symbol table (to look up `table`) and then a second access to look up the function. Saying something like `local insert,read,write = table.insert,io.read,io.write` somewhere in the file scope will do the trick. Doing it the function scope will work, but will re-create those locals on every call to the function.
9. You are using `t` as an array, and a pattern like `t[#t+1] = expression` is a very common idiom for simply appending an item to the array. Not only is it faster than calling `table.insert` (even after localizing the value), but it is also clearer.
10. You don't appear to be using the individual counts of part sizes for anything else. So there really isn't any need to be keeping the array at all. Of course, a likely creaping feature would be to produce a report that summarizes the number of each size, the number of brackets, and then includes totals. In that case, keeping a table makes sense.
11. At the command line, you are going to discover some of the mysteries of stream buffered I/O. In particular, `stdout` is line buffered (on linux and Windows by default, and almost certainly also on Mac) as long as the output is a terminal and not a file or pipe. Line buffered I/O is not guaranteed to be synchronized between streams. So your prompts are likely to not actually be visible to the user when you stop to read their answer. One way to work around this is to always print a newline, which will cause the entire line to be output. Another is to call `io.flush()` after each call to `io.write()`.
12. Put some consideration into error handling. Not just what happens if `io.write` fails, but what happens when your user answers "none" or "three" instead of the expected "0" or "3". Users do that. Your code uses an implicit conversion from string to number and will fail with a *very* messy error message if that conversion fails. Consider explicitly calling `tonumber()`, and then consider what to do when it returns `nil`. Even explicitly writing `(tonumber(answer) or 0) * 3` is better than just `answer * 3` because it converts all non-numbers into the number 0. Even better would be guide the user to valid entry.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I greatly appreciate the points you've mentioned.